# How do I use SFTP without SSH?

Tags: server, sftp

I want a fast and flexible file server but I don't need encryption or authentication.  How can I use SFTP for this on Linux systems?

Comment: Good question - and even better answer. But this is [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please move your posts to [su] or [sf] (delete here, re-post there).

Comment: "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center."

Comment: OK, so re-post it at an appropriate site. And leave it to the community to get rid of this one.

Comment: I tried posting it at Serverfault (https://serverfault.com/questions/1092940/how-do-i-use-sftp-without-ssh/1093006?noredirect=1#comment1426611_1093006).  It did not go well.

Comment: serverfault:  "Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFTP happens to be used by SSH servers but it's a well-developed protocol that works well on its own.  The sftp-server developed by OpenSSH has no dependency on an SSH server; sftp-server uses standard input/output.  (Other SFTP servers are similar.)

It is trivial to share a filesystem via SFTP, similar to what you might do with NFS but without the need for root access.  I'll use socat as the daemon for this ad-hoc example, but xinetd would make a more permanent solution.  The location of sftp-server is from my Ubuntu installation of the openssh-sftp-server package.

On the server:

```
$ mkdir shared_to_the_world
$ cd shared_to_the_world
$ socat tcp-listen:1234,reuseaddr,fork exec:/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

On the client:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/sftp_test
$ sshfs -o reconnect,ssh_command="nc my_sftp_server_address 1234 --" : /tmp/sftp_test
$ cd /tmp/sftp_test
```

Now your client (and anyone else's!) can seamlessly work with the files in the shared directory on the server.  Both read and write are enabled, so be careful.

Consider using socat listen's "bind" and "range" options to limit the access to your server.

Answer (score -4):

You can’t use SFTP without SSH.  Take a look at :  https://www.ssh.com/ssh/sftp/  (**emphasis** mine) :

“ SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol) is a secure file transfer protocol. **It runs over the SSH protocol.**. It supports the full security and authentication functionality of SSH.

...

SFTP port number is the SSH port 22 ... It is basically just an SSH server. **Only once the user has logged in to the server using SSH can the SFTP protocol be initiated.** There is no separate SFTP port exposed on servers. “

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13 (emphasis mine):
The SSH File Transfer Protocol provides secure file transfer functionality **over any reliable, bidirectional octect stream**.

Comment: That same document says “ This protocol assumes that it runs over a secure channel, such as a channel in [RFC4251]” (ie SSH), so since you’re going to have to have a secure channel like ssh, it may as well be ssh !  There are approaches to provide SFTP without allowing SSH login options - see https://serverfault.com/questions/354615/allow-sftp-but-disallow-ssh

Comment: @racraman OP explicitly wrote that he *"don't need encryption or authentication"* – Also you (and the question you have linked) mistake *"SSH"* and *"shell"*. You cannot connect to **regular** SFTP server without SSH (this question is not about regular SFTP).